# ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2. when using numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, random-forest

I have two numpy arrays

```
import numpy as np

temp_1 = np.array([['19.78018766'],
 ['19.72487359'],
 ['19.70280336'],
 ['19.69589641'],
 ['19.69746018']])

temp 2 = np.array([['43.8'],
 ['43.9'],
 ['44'],
 ['44.1'],
 ['44.2']])
```

and I am preparing `X = np.stack((temp_1,temp_2), axis=-1)`
which looks something like this

```
 X = [[['19.78018766' '43.8']]
 [['19.72487359' '43.9']]
 [['19.70280336' '44']]
 [['19.69589641' '44.1']]
 [['19.69746018' '44.2']]]
```

I have another variable Y which is also a numpy array

```
Y = np.array([['28.78'],
     ['32.72'],
     ['15.70'],
     ['32.69'],
     ['55.69']])
```

I am trying to run the RandomforestRegressor model

where

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
clf = RandomForestRegressor()
clf.fit(X,Y)
```

However, it is giving me this error

```
ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `X` and `Y` shapes are different `(5, 1, 2) != (5,1)`.

Just reshape your `X` data to the number of samples you have

```
# In this example 5 samples
X = X.reshape(5, 2)
```